# Unable to serve flask RESTful API using gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

My application is in the following structure:

```
└── wsgi_home
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    └── main.py
```

I import everything from a folder called `entry`:

```
from entry.main import main as flask_app


app = flask_app(None, is_wsgi=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=9080)
```

Every time I run this application using gunicorn I get:

```
[2022-02-11 09:37:07 +0000] [1406] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.10.0
[2022-02-11 09:37:07 +0000] [1406] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:9080 (1406)
[2022-02-11 09:37:07 +0000] [1406] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-02-11 09:37:07 +0000] [1410] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1410
Failed to find application object 'main' in 'wsgi_main'
[2022-02-11 09:37:07 +0000] [1410] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1410)
[2022-02-11 09:37:07 +0000] [1406] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2022-02-11 09:37:07 +0000] [1406] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

plz changes in your file:-

app = Flask(**name**)

app.run(debug=False)

Procfile
web: gunicorn app:app

Comment: After editing the file I get the same issue `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:9080 'entry:wsgi'` -> `Failed to find application object 'wsgi' in 'entry'`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: do have download gunicorn  command=> pip install gunicorn  make Procfile and put web: gunicorn app:app